# WebView navigation: GoBack() leads to a white page if HtmlWebViewSource is used

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have a [`WebView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.WebView/), which gets a [`HtmlWebViewSource`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource/) as content:

```
this.webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
{
    Html = "<p>some html string</p><a href='http://www.google.com'>External link</a>",
};
```

If I navigate away (by clicking on an external link added to the content before) and then call [`GoBack()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.GoBack()/) I get an empty white screen. It seems that the source is overwritten by clicking on the link.

Because the content I show isn't 100% static, I can't use a local html page as an URL. What should I do? I tried to set the `BaseUrl` without success. Furthermore, I thought I can use `OnAppearing()` or the `Navigated` event, to reload my initial content, but the events are not realiable called as I would expect.

Caveat: I've only tested this with Android (simulator and device).

PS: Other things I encountered:

- Loading a page (through clicking on the external link) seems sometimes to work and sometimes not on the simulator (and it takes too much time).
- [`CanGoBack`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.CanGoBack/) is only `true` if the page has been fully loaded. Otherwise you get `false`, despite the content is already shown on the screen (but not fully loaded).
- [`Navigated`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.Navigated/) seems to be called too late (e.g. the page was popped off already).
- Checking for `CanGoBack` in `Navigated` is not really possible, because of the different async times.
- [Navigating](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/WebView/) back seems not to be a good idea at all. Because of the here described issues it is not possible to include a back button, which reliably first navigates back if possible and finally dismisses the page.
- [`WebView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#Content) doesn't open a PDF file, when linked to